# Missing Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mobile

I'm trying to upload an application to the AppStore, but I have a weird error. I already sign my apps and selected my profiles for debug and distribution. Also I tried to sign it with .App folder and MobileProvision. 
I have built with Release-iphoneos and Release-iphonesimulator but nothing works.

So, if you have any idea please help me, I'm getting crazy.

[image: App signed]

[image: The error when I'm uploading by Loader application.]

Comment: have you tried doing the submission through an archive in Organizer? That walks you through the flow more of creating the package and submitting than the app loader so you may avoid a potential mistake in how you created your ipa.

Comment: Thank you so much, but It didn't work.
I solve it revoking my production certificate and creating again with distribution mobile provision.